# C++ object reference corruption

Tags: c++, object, reference

Creating a reference to an object results in that reference being corrupt. This is absolutely bizarre as it seems to be simple C++ functionality. Another odd thing is that the problem seems to have appeared without changes to any relevant code (that I'm aware of). If I had to guess, I'd say this has something to do with the DirectX code involved.

Here is the code:

```
// the header file of the class of the problem object
#pragma once

#include<vector>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<xnamath.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

#define float2 XMFLOAT2
#define float4 XMFLOAT4

namespace DXLib
{
    struct Sprite
    {
        char* imagename;
        float2 pos;
        float rot;
        float2 scale;
        float4 rgba;
    };

    struct Rect
    {
        float2 pos;
        float2 size;
        float4 color;
    };

    struct Text
    {
        std::string string;
        float2 pos;
    };

    class D3DDraw
    {
    public:
        D3DDraw(int maxdepth = 0);
        ~D3DDraw(void);
        void DrawSprite(char* imagename, float2 pos, int depth = 0, float rot = 0.0f, XMFLOAT2 scale = XMFLOAT2(1, 1), float4 rgba = float4(1, 1, 1, 1));
        //void DrawRect(float2 pos, float2 size, float4 color);
        void DrawDXText(std::string string, float2 pos);
        void Clear(void);

    public:
        std::vector<vector<Sprite>> depths_;
        std::vector<Text> texts_;
        int maxdepth_;  // set on initialize, do not change
        float2 spriteoffset_;
    };
}


// the header file for the base class for the class in which the problem occurs
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include"D3DCore.h"
#include"D3DRender.h"
#include"D3DDraw.h"
#include"DXInput.h"
#include<cassert>
using namespace DXLib;


const UINT uWindowSizeX = 1000;
const UINT uWindowSizeY = 800;


class Application
{
public:
    Application();
    ~Application();
    HRESULT Run();

protected:
    virtual void Update(void);

private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

protected:
    D3DDraw m_cDraw;
    DXInput m_cInput;

private:
    HWND m_hWnd;
    D3DCore m_cCore;
    D3DRender m_cRender;
};


// the class header file
#pragma once
#include"stdafx.h"
#include"VGraphics.h"
#include"EntityPool.h"
#include"VUI.h"
#include"Manager.h"

class VApp : public Application
{
public:
    VApp(void);
    ~VApp(void);
    virtual void Update(void) override;

private:
    void Log(double dTime);  // prints log info to console every nth frame

private:
    int m_iTime;
    VGraphics m_cGraphics;
    EntityPool m_cPool;
    VUI m_cVUI;
    Manager m_cManager;
};


// the function in which the problem occurs
void VApp::Update(void)
{
    double dTime = (GetTickCount() - m_iTime) / 1000.0;

    D3DDraw& rcDraw = m_cDraw; // that object is initialized and just fine
    // that reference now points to an uninitialized object
    m_cVUI.Tick(m_cInput, m_cDraw, m_cPool, m_cManager);

    m_cManager.Tick();

    m_cGraphics.Draw(m_cVUI.GetView(), m_cPool, m_cDraw);

    Log(dTime);

    m_iTime = GetTickCount();
    Sleep(15);
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense and probably isn't related to the issue.  Make a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Yeah I know, and what else is really strange is that it became a recent problem, without any changes to relevant code (that I'm aware of)

Comment: no, I don't mean that your _problem_ makes no sense, I mean that _the words you put on this page_ make no sense.  Please make a SSCCE, and edit the question to be clearer, and then we will be able to help you.

Comment: One idea: create a stack local copy of the vars that need to be refs and see if the same thing is happening (meaning create a D3DDraw& on the stack to pass to Tick).  Is there any reason the *this pointer would go out of scope?  Is Tick trying to store a copy of the ref objects?

Comment: That was a brilliant suggestion silverjam! I attempted to create a reference to the same object in the calling function and the same problem occurred

Comment: Not from what I can tell. The class definition is listed and it doesn't inherit anything

Comment: Never mind, operator&() doesn't get called until you actually use the & operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but changing the access specifier here:

```
protected:
    D3DDraw m_cDraw;
    DXInput m_cInput;
```

To `public` solved the problem, it's a hack but I'm okay with that :D

Thanks anyway for attempting to help

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my attempt at a SSCCE, but I couldn't get it to fail (probably has something to do with accessing a protected member through a [pointer to the wrong kind of object](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr129.htm)):

```
class Thing 
{ 
public:
    int value;
    Thing() { value = 42; }
    ~Thing() { };
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { }
    ~Foo() { }

public:
    void CallMethod()
    {
        Method();
    }

protected:
    virtual void Method()
    {
    }

    Thing m_x;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar() { }
    ~Bar() { }

    virtual void Method() override
    {
        Thing& x = m_x;
        printf("%d\n", x.value);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo f;
    Foo& rf = f;

    printf("%p\n", &rf);

    Bar bar;

    Foo& rfoo = bar;
    rfoo.CallMethod();

    return 0;
}
```